# how to create HttpsServer object same like HttpServer object in jersey

Tags: java, https, glassfish, jersey, jax-rs

How to create HttpsServer Object & config webservice class using jersey as given below code to create HttpServer.

```
import java.net.URI;
import org.glassfish.jersey.jdkhttp.JdkHttpServerFactory;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

public class ServerInit {

    static final String BASE_URI = "https://localhost:9099/";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HttpServer server = null;

        ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig(HelloWorld.class);
        URI endpoint = new URI(BASE_URI);
        server = JdkHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(endpoint, rc);

        System.out.println("console : Press Enter to stop the server. ");
        System.in.read();
        server.stop(0);

    }
}
```